# Vuejs lazy loading routes in webpack template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I have created vuejs project with vue-cli tools and webpack template.

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

I don't know how to implement lazy loading on routes with templates

currently i have two routes in `router/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Test from '@/components/Test'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
   mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/test',
      name: 'test',
      component: Test
    }
  ]
})
```

And its imported in `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

But it doesn't contain the lazy loading implementation how can i do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using

```
import Test from '@/components/Test'
```

use as

```
const Test = () => import('@/components/Test');
```

[lazy loading Documentataion](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nice way to do this:

```
function load (component) {
  return () => import(`@/${component}.vue`)
}

...
routes: [
    { path: '/', component: load('Hello') },
```